# Pandas Python: append data frame - text

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have the following data frame. How can I append the rows corresponding to the same user on the same day?
Python-Pandas

```
user date text
A    1-1  how
A    1-1  are
A    3-1  the dog
B    1-2  hi
B    1-2  there
B    3-2  be good


user date text
A    1-1  how are
A    3-1  the dog
B    1-2  hi there
B    3-2  be good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a groupby and string join:

```
df.groupby(['user','date'])['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

> Note:`' '.join` is a shorter version of `lambda x: ' '.join(x)`.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
user,date,text
A,1-1,how
A,1-1,are
A,3-1,the dog
B,1-2,hi
B,1-2,there
B,3-2,be good'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep=',')

df = df.groupby(['user','date'])['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  user date      text
0    A  1-1   how are
1    A  3-1   the dog
2    B  1-2  hi there
3    B  3-2   be good
```

---

Also look at this if it helps. The quick version to group all items in lists.

```
print(df.groupby(['user','date'])['text'].apply(list).reset_index())
#  user date         text
#0    A  1-1   [how, are]
#1    A  3-1    [the dog]
#2    B  1-2  [hi, there]
#3    B  3-2    [be good]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `pivot_table()`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['user', 'date'], values='text', aggfunc=' '.join).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  user date      text
0    A  1-1   how are
1    A  3-1   the dog
2    B  1-2  hi there
3    B  3-2   be good
```